# ArgumentOutOfRange exception on PagedCollectionView when removing items from the underlying ObservableCollection

Tags: silverlight

I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects. I have a `PagedCollectionView` constructed from the `ObservableCollection` which is bound to a listbox.

When I call `Remove` on `ObservableCollection` PagedCollectionView throws an the ArgumentOutOfRange exception. Paramter:Index

What must I do to Remove an item from an ObservableCollection that is used this way.

**Update:**
This issue may be related to the following bug reported on
[Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595364/argumentoutofrangeexception-in-pagecollectionview)  If that's true, then is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `RemoveAt`? Do you have the same problem?

Annoying question: Do you **need** `PagedCollectionView`? (Are you using paging in your listbox?)

The **best** solution is to use Remove or RemoveAt on the actual `PagedCollectionView`, however. (If you do indeed even need it)

Comment: I have one collection of data, that needs to be displayed by two different lists.  I'm using the PagedCollectionView for its filtering, and sorting (not it's paging)  If there is something better to bind to I'm all for it.

Comment: In your case, you should try to use the `Remove(At)` of the `PagedCollectionView`. I suspect your problem has to do with some of the items being virtualized away. You'd probably be best to stick with `Remove`, that way you don't have to worry about the indices.